# Python how to iter month with out other months date

Tags: python, date

I am trying to get all days of november as dates in november:

```
import calendar

calen = calendar.Calendar()        
calen_iter = calen.itermonthdates(2017,11)

for c in calen_iter: 
    print (c)
```

I am getting the following output:

```
2017-10-30
2017-10-31
2017-11-01
2017-11-02
2017-11-03
<snipped lots of correct output>
2017-11-28
2017-11-29
2017-11-30
2017-12-01
2017-12-02
2017-12-03
```

---

I dont want these dates - why do they appear?

```
2017-10-30
2017-10-31
2017-12-01
2017-12-02
2017-12-03
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is by design, see `help(calen.itermonthdays)` (emphasis mine):

> `itermonthdates(year, month)` method of `calendar.Calendar` instance
>
> Return an iterator for one month. The iterator will yield `datetime.date`
>   values and will always iterate through complete weeks, so **it will yield
>   dates outside the specified month**.

Add a condition to filter out days from other months:

```
for c in calen_iter: 
    if c.month == 11:
        print(c)
```

Or more compactly using a list comprehension:

```
days_of_november = [d for d in calen.itermonthdates(2017, 11) if d.month == 11]
```